# Java: Had to move away from using enums as keys for HashMaps, why does an enum keyed HashMap.get() returns null pointer?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

```
enum MyKeys { AKEY, BKEY, CKEY } 
Map <MyKeys, Clazz> zzz = new HashMap<MyKeys, Clazz>();
zzz.put(MyKeys.BKEY, new Clazz());
zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY).setValues(someValues);
Clazz xxx = zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY);//returns null
```

However this simple change makes it return the proper value:

```
enum MyKeys { AKEY, BKEY, CKEY } 
Map <String, Clazz> zzz = new HashMap<String, Clazz>();
zzz.put(MyKeys.BKEY, new Clazz());
zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY).setValues(someValues);
Clazz xxx = zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY.toString());//doesn't returns null
```

Why?

Comment: how do you fill up the hashmap in first one ? There is also enummap as well btw

Comment: Did you define BKEY as enum before using it? Otherwise you have to use it as `MyKeys.BKEY` instead of only `BKEY`. so is `zzz.put(MyKeys.BKEY, "bla")` and `zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY)`

Comment: Provide a complete program which reproduces the problem. Enums are fine as keys in HashMaps, and what you don't show is where the problem is.

Comment: "Filled up zzz" might be important to show...

Comment: What's wrong with using `EnumMap`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick comments. Actually, I was using BKEY as MyKeys.BKEY. As for how I was filling up zzz, I will add it right away. JB Nizet<-If I knew where the problem was, I wouldn't had to come here, no? : ) I will lookup EnumMap as well.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name <- Do you mean I should replace HashMap with EnumMap? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/enummap_values.htm

Comment: @coffeenet The Code you pasted does **not** reproduce your problem. Please give us a minimal problem example. P.S. You forgot a `new` before `HashMap` and the `HashMap` should have `<MyKeys,Clazz>` as type parameters.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and even after fixing it (see @Absurd-Mind's comment) `xxx` is not `null`. You have some problem in your code but it is not related to using enums as keys.

Comment: Your second code snippet has bigger problems - how can you put `MyKeys.BKEY` as a key into a `Map<String, Clazz>`? The compiler won't let you because `MyKeys.BKEY` doesn't have the type `String`.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt It actually does return null. And, strangely enough it let me without any compiling issues. I am guessing the problem is with how the enums are used in HashMap as keys. What actual values of that enum are used.

Comment: @coffeenet Please provide a small but complete example with a main method which shows your problem. I'm positive that there is something missing.

Answer (score 3):

```
Map <MyKeys, Clazz> zzz = new HashMap<MyKeys, String>();
// this means it won't return null, the value is initialized
zzz.put(MyKeys.BKEY, new Clazz()); 
// this is confusing part ... somevalues might be null
zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY).setValues(someValues);
Clazz xxx = zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY); //definitely won't return null
```

are you sure its the hashmap returning null, and not the result of the getValues(), of the clazz put into hashmap.

YOu have an error elsewhere, try the below in a [web based compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static class Clazz {
        public String val;
        public void setValues(String someValues){
            val=someValues;
        }

    }
    public enum MyKeys { AKEY, BKEY, CKEY; }
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Map<MyKeys, Clazz> zzz = new HashMap<MyKeys, Clazz>();
        // this means it won't return null, the value is initialized
        zzz.put(MyKeys.BKEY, new Clazz());
        // this is confusing part ... somevalues might be null
        zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY).setValues("someValues");
        Clazz xxx = zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY);
        System.out.println(xxx.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is identical to the actual code I am using in-terms of structure. Furthermore, the "someValues" is definitely not null in my program. I debugged it. 1- by hand I looked into zzz, BKEY allocation has someValues present. 2- Out of curiosity, I even went ahead and xxx = new Clazz() before doing the zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY), and xxx turns null right after the "get" line. 3- Just by changing the key to String, and using MyKeys.BKEY.toString(), and WITHOUT touching anything else, it worked flawlessly. So, I am sure it is an issue with enums.

Comment: One more note though, the definition and instantiation of zzz is inside one package, and the zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY) code is inside a different package. I am thinking that the mapping of enums inside the HashMap is done by using addresses of the enums that change from package to package rather than constant values such as the BKEY text. Thank you for taking the time to read this long comment.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the correct value if you use

```
String xxx = zzz.get(MyKeys.BKEY);
```

So you would actually need to declare BKEY as an enum of MyKeys before using it in the method parameter.

Comment: in the example code you can see BKEY is declared, an dit wouldn;t return null it would be a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

I've used java's `EnumMap`

see this example:

```
public enum Colors{
    BLUE, YELLOW, BROWN, RED;
}
```

Then initiate your `EnumMap`

```
// initialization
EnumMap<Colors, String> stateMap = new EnumMap<Colors, String>(Colors.class);
```

Enjoy!